# Why not apply one hot encoder , knowing that there is no error during running file?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to apply one hot encoding to one column which is "drive_wheels" 
However, on running there is no error and no change to the dataset!
Is there any error in the code?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as  np

df = pd.read_csv('onehotencoding.csv')

df.head()

obj_df = df.select_dtypes(include=['object']).copy()
obj_df.head()

pd.get_dummies(obj_df, columns=["drive_wheels"]).head()
```

Answer (score 1):

[pd.get_dummies()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html#pandas-get-dummies) doesn't have an `inplace` switch. Therefore, you need to join the resulting DataFrame to your original:

```
dummies = pd.get_dummies(obj_df, columns=["drive_wheels"]).head()
combined = df.join(dummies)
```

For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(list('AABBABA'), columns=['cats'])
dummies = pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['cats'])
combined = df.join(dummies)
print(combined)
```

Which gives you:

```
  cats  cats_A  cats_B
0    A       1       0
1    A       1       0
2    B       0       1
3    B       0       1
4    A       1       0
5    B       0       1
6    A       1       0
```